# Autofill fields of pyQgis script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have three fields of output vector layer in Qgis script:

```
##output_vector_first=output vector
##output_vector_second=output vector
##output_vector_third=output vector
```

When user fill first field I want recreate his path and use it for the next two fields.

For example:

1. User fill the first field: **C:Users/myPath/first.shp**
2. Then the next two fields will be autofilled with: **C:Users/myPath/second.shp** and **C:Users/myPath/third.shp**

Is it possible dynamically change field values in PyQgis script?

Comment: You could do something similar if you remove the second and third output and then run the script as a **batch process** by right-clicking your script from the _Processing Toolbox_.