# Autofill field parameter based on parent layer in Processing Provider

Tags: qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I'm building a custom Processing Provider and would like my field dropbox to be dynamically filled with the first valid field of the associated parent layer. Currently, the dropbox list is updated if I change the parent layer (great), but it doesn't select any field (keeps the box empty). Is is possible to query this same list and autoselect the first field in the list? I should add that I don't want to hard code the name of the field as it may change.

```py
class customAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT_vector = 'INPUT_vector'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(self.INPUT_vector,
                                                            self.tr('Vector Layer'),
                                                            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]))
        
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField(self.INPUT_field,
                                                      self.tr('Selected Field'),
                                                      defaultValue = None,
                                                      parentLayerParameterName = 'INPUT_vector',
                                                      type = QgsProcessingParameterField.Numeric))
```

There is this [other similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199316/autofill-fields-of-pyqgis-script), but it didn't really got a full answer (and was with QGIS 2.x).

Comment: You may look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356729/using-a-custom-ui-for-a-qgis-processing-algorithm-script You will need to create your own widget but you will be able to use a signal when choosing first element to fill correctly the second one